# How to get GCC or CLANG to throw warnings when there is a missing function definition?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I'm coding in pure C.

I'm familiar with `-Wmissing-prototypes` which will issue a warning when the function prototype is missing.

How about one for when there is no function definition?

This would be useful while refactoring a library when in the process of adding/removing functions, you had a good idea for a new function, but forgot to implement it.

Comment: Not possible.  The fact a function is missing in C is not detectable until the final link step as another file can always add it.  This step occurs post compilation so the compiler cannot warn.

Comment: Any decent `IDE` worth anything should tell you that.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a test for the new function in place before you add it, so that your testing spots its absence immediately?

Comment: Add a `#warning not implemented`  when you write the prototype/incomplete definition to remind you.

Comment: The linker *should* give you a link error. (The C standard doesn't actually require this, but linkers do it as a quality of implementation issue)

Comment: If the function is only used from the current TU then mark the prototype `static`, again you *should* get a warning if there is later no function body.

Comment: While the linker *should* give an error, weak symbols (on multiple platforms) interfere with that.  See for example http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/chapter2-11/index.html